# How to stop my service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Please also see Edit 2 (below)

I have extended `NotificationListenerService` and implemented several of its methods including the `onDestroy()` method (but not the `onBind()` or `onStartCommand()` method, as I don't need them, as far as I know). However when I call `selfStop()` `onDestroy()` isn't called.

I know there are other links out there about calling `selfStop()`, but I haven't found any solution for my problem.

My service is started by the system using the following code in the `android-manifest`:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Again, when I try to call `stopSelf()` in the `onCreate()` method (if certain conditions are met) the `onDestroy()` method isn't called...the service isn't destroyed.

It is constantly using RAM (I know it's running because I can see it under Settings -> Apps -> Running (on my smartphone))

Does anyone know why `stopSelf()` might not be executed/run? Do I have to do something in the `onBind()` method (e.g. change the returned constant)? 
Is it even possible to stop my `service` that `extends NotificationListenerService`, so that it isn't running before it's called again by the system?
Do I have to call `unbind()` before calling `stopSelf()`? If so then using which `Context` and `ServiceConnection`?

**Edit 1**

Here is my code:

```
public class Core extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("abc", "onCreateService");
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    //check main switch state:
    check = prefs.getBoolean("mainswitch", true);
    Toast.makeText(Core.this, Boolean.toString(check), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("abc", Boolean.toString(check));
    if(check == false){
        stopSelf();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("abc", "onDestroyService");
}
}
```

**Edit 2**

If I have problems destroying my service that extends the `NotificationListenerService` (see above) would it be smart to create a second `service` (e.g. MirrorClass) that basically mirrors the  `NotificationListenerService`? I would then just refer to that class and its methods from the actual service that extends `NotificationListenerService`. Presumably that would then be easier to `destroy` as I was the one that started it (unlike the service that extends `NotificationListenerService` that is started/called by the android-system itself)

Something like this:

```
public class Core extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    MirrorClass.mOnNotificationPosted(sbn) //This is the reference to the other class
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){}
```

Would really appreciate some guidance/help here, it's starting to do my head in, thanks

Comment: can you post the code of ur service?

Comment: @eldjon I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new service that does all of the work for you, instead of doing the work in this service that extends `NotificationListenerService`. All you do then is use the `startService()` method once you want to do some work and presumably you will send some `extras` with that `intent` containing the posted notification. 
It is then very easy to stop that service (that does the work for you and doesn't extend `NotificationListenerService`) using the `stopSelf()` method. 
Stopping the `NotificationListenerService` itself using the `stopSelf()` method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try overrides `onStartCommand()` in your Service with `START_NOT_STICKY` flag:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I tried the START_NOT_STICKY constant, but that seems to only have an influence when the service is terminated due to lack of memory on the device...
It doesn't have any influence when I call stopSelf(). 
But thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: Maybe it works, but frequency of receiving events is high so it seems like this service is running all the time? Why do you need it to be stopped if every change to notifications will trigger this service again?

Comment: I only need my service (that extends NotificationListenerService) to be active/alive when I receive a notification. I don't want it to run constantly...when I check my app in 'running apps' on my device it's using over 100MB (more than any other application). It should be possible to stop my service/destroy it and let it be created again once it receives a call from the android system (that a notification has been received), right?
Thanks for the help

Comment: any progress? i want this as well

Answer (score 0):

Place command

```
stopSelf();
```

to

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
```

Make some variable for checking if service should be stopped.