# Cannot instantiate the type NotificationListenerService in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the `getActiveNotifications()` from the [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#NotificationListenerService()) class, 
however it doesn't work, I have tried these to ways:

**1)**

```
    NotificationListenerService nls = new NotificationListenerService();
    activeNotifications = nls.getActiveNotifications();
```

**2)**

```
    activeNotifications = NotificationListener.class.getActiveNotifications();
```

But for 1) I get this error:

> Cannot instantiate the type NotificationListenerService

and for 2) I get this error:

```
The method getActiveNotifications() is undefined for the type Class<NotificationListenerService>
```

This seems to be simple Java but I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?
Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what api level did you get these errors?

Comment: @Olayinka I am using this in my manifest:
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
the method getActiveNotification() was introduced in api 18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `NotificationListenerService`, you need to create a custom class that extends from `NotificationListenerService`.
You can't instatiate it, the System will do it for you.

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service android:name="your.package.name.MyNLS"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Create a NotificationListenerService class:

```
public class MyNLS extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }

}
```

Use this code to send the user to the Notification Listener Settings:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

Then, inside your service you can call this to have the list of Active notifications:

```
for (StatusBarNotification sbn : getActiveNotifications()) {
    /// do something
}
```

Comment: I have already done this, but the problem is that I want to send the active Notifications from this class that extends NLS to another service of mine that will do the work for me. However I have experienced some problems concerning file descriptors (see link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463807/sending-object-as-parcel-with-file-descriptors-through-intent-causes-exception)). So I am trying to get the StatusBarNotification[] that is returned by getActiveNotifications() straight from the class that will do the work for me, so I don't have to send it through an intent

Comment: Why do you want to do it from another Service, can't you directly perform your process in that first Service?

Comment: I cannot stop that service that extends NotificationListenerService using stopSelf() thus there are a number of processes that are never destroyed which uses even more RAM than it already uses without those additional processes. I addressed that issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209813/how-to-stop-my-service), thanks for the help.
Is there no way to access the getActiveNotifications() method without extending the NLS?

Comment: @REG1 I think that both of your two questions are answered. Mark the answear as the correct one, and if you have more questions, open a new question ;)