# How can I stop a NotificationListenerService?

Tags: java, android, notifications, listener

I have written a subclass of `NotificationListenerService` which runs in the background while my app is running. However, I want to allow the user to turn off the service, in the event that they want to save battery. I implement this as follows:

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_quit:
                Intent serviceStopIntent = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.communicator_intent));
                serviceStopIntent.putExtra("command", "shutdown");
                sendBroadcast(serviceStopIntent);

        }
```

ListeningService.java

```
public class ListeningService extends NotificationListenerService {
      public void doStop() {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "***** DEBUG_jwir3: Requesting stop of ListeningService");
        this.stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mCommunicator);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "***** DEBUG_jwir3: Destroying ListeningService");
        mMessageHandler.shutdown();
    }

    class ListeningCommunicator extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "***** DEBUG_jwir3: Received command");
            if (aIntent.getStringExtra("command").equals("shutdown")) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "***** DEBUG_jwir3: Received shutdown command");
                ListeningService.this.doStop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I've simplified the code, but I can give more examples, if necessary).

I know that the `BroadcastReceiver` is receiving the message, and I know that `doStop()` is being called (due to the log message), but the service's `onDestroy()` is not being called. Also, I can tell from `Settings -> Apps -> Running` that the service is still running.

I've been researching this, and it seems that (for some reason) `NotificationListenerService` doesn't respond to `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` requests. I found [How to stop my service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209813/how-to-stop-my-service) The accepted answer here suggests wrapping the `NotificationListenerService` in another `Service`, and then stopping/starting this as necessary. This seems like it won't help, though, since the `NotificationListenerService` would still need to be stopped somehow, and this wrapping service wouldn't be able to stop it, either.

It seems like there should be a better way to do this than the accepted answer, and I'm wondering if anyone has insight into how I might go about this?